# Script to automate the cloning of all the repos to local associated with the git account

Tags: git, bash, github, c#-3.0, git-bash

I'm working on a script to automate the task of getting all the repositories for a git hub url and then cloning them to local, if the clone is already present then we must update the latest changes.

I've been looking into

1. Git bash, but I could not figure out a way on to how to get all the repo's and the url to clone them associated with the account.
2. I've looked in to octokit for c#, but I'm not really sure if that is ideal for this task.

Answer (score 1):

> Git bash, but I could not figure out a way on to how to get all the repo's and the url to clone them associated with the account.

It is a simple curl, using the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/). See for instance [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rd2b/4387863)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the user:
user="rd2b"

# Lists github repositories:
curl -s https://api.github.com/users/$user/repos | sed -n 's/.*clone_url.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/ p'

# Clone all repositories:
for i in `curl -s https://api.github.com/users/$user/repos | sed -n 's/.*clone_url.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/ p'`
do
  git clone "$i" "github-$(basename $i)"
done
```

You will need to adapt the script in order for:

- testing the existence of a local folder for a given repo
- if the folder exists, `cd` into it and do a `git pull` (or at least a `git fetch`).

If you have a *large* number or GitHub repositories, you might have to take into account the **[pagination](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/)**.
See [this gist as an example](https://gist.github.com/michfield/4525251).

Comment: Isn't there a limit to how many repos are returned in the API call?  IIRC paging is required.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I believe you can go up to 100 per page. Hence the second gist link I refer to in my answer: https://gist.github.com/michfield/4525251

Comment: Sorry, missed that part.  Thank you.  The "mirror all repos" functionality should be considered by Github to be easily scriptable.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I agree. They seem to release a lot more features these days. Maybe GitHub Desktop will provide that.